# Binding to a method with access to local variables

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I've been playing around with WPF for a while and I like how it is extremely versatile. I have read how to bind to a method with a single parameter (using a converter). However, purely hypothetically, is there a way to bind to a function that has access to local variables in the class?

For example, say I have a ListBox of TextBoxes to be bound to a List of Strings, defined and manipulated in the code behind, through a DataTemplate. Instead of displaying the entire string, however, each TextBox only displays the first N words of its corresponding string, which is easily done by a method that accepts the string and N as parameters. N, however, is free for the user to configure, and thus must be a local variable. For this to be a flexible control, N cannot be a static variable as we want it to be possible to have many windows with such ListBoxes with different Ns; besides, that would be extremely inelegant.

Now we can't use a converter as converters only accept a single variable, while we need to access an N. We can't cheat and use a static variable either.

We also cannot bind the TextBoxes to a local property that has access to local variables as we do to normal objects, as we are binding to a whole List of objects.

From what I see, ObjectDataProvider only allows you to call a method of the class of a given object, and not a method defined in the window. It is, I believe, a waste to create a new class and copy N to every instance of the class just for the sake of achieving such simple functionality.

Of course in a real scenario it's possible to sidetrack this problem through such measures as creating an object including the string and N as in the previous paragraph, or including both the string and another string comprising the first two words of the string precomputed. I'm just asking whether such a functionality exists for WPF because it fits well into the concept WPF is based on and I believe that such a functionality would be useful some way or another.

I'm sorry if the solution is immediately obvious; I've been searching for hours.

If there is a solution, is there a way to do so completely in XAML, with only the method defined in the code behind?

EDIT: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, Clemens... N can't be passed as ConvertParameter as it is not possible to bind to ConvertParameter. As for the first suggestion, I'm trying it out, but I'm getting an error `Specified cast is not valid.` at the Convert method of the IMultiValueConverter. Rather than N, values[1] is DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. Below is the code:

XAML

```
<MultiBinding>
    <MultiBinding.Converter>
        <my:StringShorternerConverter />
    </MultiBinding.Converter>
    <Binding Path="Title" />
    <Binding ElementName="me" Path="N" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Inside StringShorternerConverter

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ShortenText((String)values[0], (Int32)values[1]);
}
```

EDIT 2: Looks like that error was due to some irrelevant mistake. Yeah, it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For feedback you should comment on an answer, otherwise the one who answered won't realize. He/she does not automatically get notified when you edit your question. For the edit itself: How is N defined and where is it set? Please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily bind to multiple properties by using a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) in conjunction with a converter that implements [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

You could also pass your variable N to the `parameter` argument of the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx) method of a normal converter by means of the [Binding.ConverterParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx)  property.